# run cmd as admin but settings apply to logged in user

Tags: vb.net, batch-file, cmd, uac

I am writing a Visual Basic program that needs to run as admin to properly execute certain commands in a batch file. However, since this changes the user who the program is run under, when I execute my commands in the batch files they apply those changes under that admin account.

Is there any way (without getting the user's password) to get UAC privileges so when the batch file runs as an Admin account, but the settings apply to the currently logged on user profile?

The program is using "requireAdministrator" in the app manifest, so all the commands such as Process.Start are being invoked by that admin account.

Comment: I'd be interested in why you're specifically needing to run commands from a batch file from VB!

Comment: Why do you want to run as a user that you don't have the password to? Suspicious... if this is possible, any windows user (or apple for that matter) should be extremely concerned.

Comment: @NekoMusume, possible solutions would be to  use the "runas" in the batch file which would require the users password or using .Password in Process.Start parameters. I would want to run some commands under the reqular user account, but cant because the program that starts the batch is running through the admin user account not the logged on user account which is where I want the commands to execute under.

Comment: @Compo, commands such as                                 My.Computer.Registry.SetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\app", "Completed", "True")

Comment: Use `icacls` command to give yourself permission to the file. The admin user has access to the files of other users. You should have no problem starting a file belonging to another user with admin cmd.

Comment: A program run by a non admin that needs elevation gets an elevation prompt for an administrator's username and password. _Prompt for credentials on the secure desktop

This is the default. When an operation requires elevation of privilege, the user is prompted on the secure desktop to enter a different user name and password. If the user enters valid credentials, the operation continues with the applicable privilege._ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/user-account-control-behavior-of-the-elevation-prompt-for-standard-users

Comment: This is from VBScript's Helpfile `Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")` `WshShell.RegWrite "HKCU\Software\ACME\FortuneTeller\MindReader", "Goocher!", "REG_SZ"`. To use it in VB.NET remove set from line `WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")` and add `dim wshshell as object`.

Comment: You also don't need to be an admin to write to your own `HKey_Current_User`.

Comment: @mark, I will try the WScript out, but the program already needs to be run as admin for other processes so when the reg keys are created the program is already runnig under the admin context, which is why I tried going the batch route because the my.computer.reg... was applying the keys under the admin account.

Comment: @DavidRohweder, I can assure you that `My.Computer.Registry.SetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\app", "Completed", "True")` is not batch file code, but VB, so you have not answered my question. What do you need to run a batch file for? Which commands are you running in a batch file which cannot be run directly from VB? As already stated, you're only making changes to the current user registry, and for that you shouldn't need to be using elevated privileges. If you're having to change users, then in order to make your registry changes, use the appropriate key, `HKU-S-ID` instead of `HKCU`.

Answer (score 1):

To run CMD as administrator, I have here a small VBScript file that can do that:

```
CreateObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe ",,,"RunAs",1
```

If you are trying to run as an administrator within the UAC prompt, this is not possible as this will be a big security breach on Windows.

Another tip, if you want to run some batch commands, better create a batch file instead of running multiple commands.
To run that batch file as administrator, use that:

```
CreateObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c BatchFile.bat",,,"RunAs",1
```

Note that I don't know how to code in Visual Basic, this is a solution for VBScript.

If that's not your answer, please let me know it.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is gonna solve this problem:

```
@echo off
:init
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set "batchPath=%~0"
for %%k in (%0) do set batchName=%%~nk
set "vbsGetPrivileges=%temp%\OEgetPriv_%batchName%.vbs"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

:checkPrivileges
NET FILE 1>NUL 2>NUL
if '%errorlevel%' == '0' ( goto gotPrivileges ) else ( goto getPrivileges )
:getPrivileges
if '%1'=='ELEV' (echo ELEV & shift /1 & goto gotPrivileges)
echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%vbsGetPrivileges%"
echo args = "ELEV " >> "%vbsGetPrivileges%"
echo For Each strArg in WScript.Arguments >> "%vbsGetPrivileges%"
echo args = args ^& strArg ^& " "  >> "%vbsGetPrivileges%"
echo Next >> "%vbsGetPrivileges%"
echo UAC.ShellExecute "!batchPath!", args, "", "runas", 1 >> "%vbsGetPrivileges%"
"%SystemRoot%\System32\WScript.exe" "%vbsGetPrivileges%" %*
exit /B

:gotPrivileges
setlocal & pushd .
cd /d %~dp0
if '%1'=='ELEV' (del "%vbsGetPrivileges%" 1>nul 2>nul  &  shift /1)

REM --------------- Batch script start here
```

Comment: please add some information explaining how your answer solves the problem - this will help others in the future